# iAd Banner Issue. Unable to see advert

Tags: ios, objective-c, iad

I am new in iAd Xcode development. I have created a Xcode application 'BasicBannerView' for iAd banner. I ran the application and received the message 'You are connected to iAd', but when I tap on the banner, I receive the message 'Leave 'BasicBannerView' and open this link in Safari?' Visiting this website will cause you to leave the app.

How can I see the banner within application?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //init BannerView object and Set Delegate
    _bannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithAdType:ADAdTypeBanner];
    _bannerView.delegate = self;

    //Set banner property AutoSize
    [_bannerView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
    [self.view addSubview:_bannerView];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self bannerCheck:NO];

    //ADBannerView *adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 50, 320, 50)];
    //[self.view addSubview:adView];
    _adBanner = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height, 320, 50)];
    _adBanner.delegate = self;
}

//called Automatically when ad is available
-(void) bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    _bannerViewDidLoadAdCount +=1;

    [self updateCountLabels];
    [self bannerCheck:YES];
}

//  Called automatically when user taps on the advert
-(BOOL) bannerViewActionShouldBegin:(ADBannerView *)banner willLeaveApplication:(BOOL)willLeave
{
    _bannerViewActionShouldBeginCount += 1;
    [self updateCountLabels];
    [self PauseAppFunctionality];

    return  YES;
}

//  Called when user finishes with advert and close the ad
-(void)bannerViewActionDidFinish:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    _bannerViewActionDidFinishCount += 1;
    [self updateCountLabels];
    [self ContiuneAppFunctionality];
}

//  Called when there is an error displaying Advert
-(void) bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    _bannerViewDidFailToReceiveAdWithErrorCount += 1;
    [self updateCountLabels];
    [self bannerCheck:YES];
}

-(void) updateCountLabels
{
    self.bannerViewDidLoadAdCountLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",_bannerViewDidLoadAdCount];
    self.bannerViewActionShouldBeginCountLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",_bannerViewActionShouldBeginCount];
    self.bannerViewActionDidFinishCountLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",_bannerViewActionDidFinishCount];
    self.bannerViewDidFailToReceivedAdWithErrorCountLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",_bannerViewDidFailToReceiveAdWithErrorCount];
}

-(void) bannerCheck:(BOOL)animated
{
    //  Get Frame
    CGRect contentFrame = self.view.bounds;
    CGRect bannerFrame = _bannerView.frame;

    //  if there is ad available show ad view else hide
    if(_bannerView.bannerLoaded) {
        bannerFrame.origin.y = contentFrame.size.height - bannerFrame.size.height;

    }
    else {
        bannerFrame.origin.y = contentFrame.size.height;
    }

    //  animate ad on or off the screen
    [UIView animateWithDuration:animated?0.20:0.0 animations:^{_bannerView.frame = bannerFrame;}];
}

-(void)cancelAd
{
    // How to cancel displayed ad:avoid if you can

    if(_bannerView.bannerViewActionInProgress) {
        [_bannerView cancelBannerViewAction];
    }
}
```

Comment: `_bannerViewDidLoadAdCount +=1` why do you have these variables and why are you incrementing them?

Comment: I have put four labels to see the actions i.e. bannerViewDidLoadAdCountLabel used to display the counts to calculate no of loaded banners so I have used _bannerViewDidLoadAdCount +=1